# can not run multiple jobs with quartz plugin using grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, jobs

hi there I'm using quartz plugin for grails.
when i have just 1 job (i used "create-job" command) everything works as expected!
this is how the job looks like and it will print every 1 second:

```
class MyFirstJob{
def concurrent = false

static triggers = {
    simple name: 'myFirstJobTrigger', startDelay: 1000, repeatInterval: 1000 }

def group = "MyGroup"

    def execute(){ 
    println "MyFirstJob run!" 
}
}
```

now if i add another job that should print every 5 sec that look like this:

```
class MySecondJob{
def concurrent = false

static triggers = {
    simple name: 'mySecondJobTrigger', startDelay: 1000, repeatInterval: 5000 }

def group = "MyGroup"

    def execute(){ 
    println "MySecondJob run!" 
}
}
```

what will happen now is that job1 will start working only every 5 seconds
it seems that quartz pluging can only have 1 job schedule 
i was wondering what am i missing or doing wrong

i even tried the next 2 lines in a file called quartz.properties under conf directory:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried turning on logging by adding `debug 'grails.app.jobs'` to the `log4j` closure in your `Config.groovy`? This may provide some addition details.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin requires the job class filename to end in 'Job'. Therefore, make sure that MyJob2 is in a file named 'My2Job.groovy' in the job folder

Comment: its my bad i gave it simple names and simple body only here so i fix the code but still i can't get to run 2 jobs so my question remain the same if anyone could help me its gonna be great

Comment: ok. i understand that this was just sample code, i was just making sure that the filenames were in the proper format. your code works fine when i run, so i can't imagine what else the problem could be